Conda package not found error with nbody kit in bccp channel
I am trying to install a Python library using conda called nbodykit, available at https://conda.anaconda.org/bccp. However, when I try to use the command
conda install -c bccp nbodykit

the same command also suggested by the guide https://nbodykit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/install.html#installing-nbodykit-with-anaconda, I receive the following error:
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - nbodykit

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bccp
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

i'm on MacOS Sonoma 14.5 and conda 24.5.0.
My thesis supervisor, who is running Linux, has no problem with the exact same command and we couldn't find the problem.
I also tried to install it using pip, but I get an error with the Cython library. Since conda should work, I would like to try to solve the issue with conda.
I tried performing a clean installation of conda and updating it, but the problem persists.
EDIT: When trying to install other libraries available in bccp, I receive the same error. Therefore, I don't think it's a problem with the nbodykit library, but rather with bccp/conda.
Thanks in advance for any responses.

Do you have an x64 or arm64 environment? Type conda info and report what it says udner "platform"

osx-arm64, it's an M2 macbook air

The package you want to install only has x64 files available, see https://anaconda.org/bccp/nbodykit you will need to create a x64 environment

As you can see on anaconda.org, the package only has osx-x64 installation candidates:

You will need to create a x64 environment, following this answer. (Make sure you have installed Rosetta 2 and open the terminal with Rosetta 2):
conda create x64Env
conda activate x64Env
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64 #This will set that all packages installed in this env will be for x64 architecture
conda install -c bccp nbodykit 


Okay, it worked. Just two notes for anyone else in the same situation. 1. Make sure you have installed Rosetta 2 and open the terminal with Rosetta 2. 2. The command is conda config --env --set subdir osx-64, without the 'x' in front of 64.

Thanks for the comment, I don't ahave a MAC to test myself, so I am glad for the feedback. I have incorporated it into the answer)
